# Jira api to search all issues in Jira using python

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I want to list/search all the issues in Jira. I have a code like :

```
url = 'https://company.com/rest/api/2/search'


auth = HTTPBasicAuth("username", "password") // I tries token as well

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}

query = {
    'jql': 'project=PRKJECTKEY',
    'startAt': 0
}
response = requests.request(
    "GET",
    url,
    headers=headers,
    auth=auth,
    params=query
)
```

I am not sure if the password should be token or the actual password and the url should be should be starting from companyname.com. This gives me `<Response [401]>` but i have all the permissions with the account.

Can someone help me with the authentication is supposed to be used this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only describe my way of accessing the JIRA-API:

###### 1. I am using an API-key for this which one can easily create online, if one has the necessary permissions

(https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/basic-auth-for-rest-apis/)

###### 2. You need to set up the Jira-object to query issues first

```
user = 'firstname.familyname@account.xx'

apikey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
server = 'https://companypage.atlassian.net'

options = {
 'server': server
}

jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=(user, apikey))
```

###### 3. Now, you can use the Jira-object to query with

```
tickets = jira.search_issues('text ~ "my search text" ORDER BY updated DESC')
```

Now, you can look what you got back and play with the results

```
for ticket in tickets:
  print(ticket)
```

For Packages, you only need to import JIRA at the top (obviously, need to install jira first):

```
from jira import JIRA
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, why don't you use `atlassian-python-api`?

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-articles/Atlassian-Python-API-s/ba-p/2091355

It's much easier to work with Jira via their own library. I have been working with Confluence via this and it's pretty simple. Take a look it may solve your problem.

EDIT: here is documentation. https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Thank you Johny for your answer :) Another answer helped me.